# Solve ODE with log and absolute value

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f(u)=-u\ln(\lvert u \rvert)$ if $u \neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$. Solve:

$$
\begin{cases}
u'(t)=f(u(t)), t \in \mathbb{R} \\
u(0)=u_0
\end{cases}
$$

For $u > 0$, I found:

$$u(t)=\exp(\exp(-t+\ln(\ln(u_0)))$$

For $u < 0$, I found:

$$u(t)=\exp(\exp(-t+\ln(\ln(-u_0))$$

All in all, for $u_0 \neq 0$, $$u(t)=\exp(\exp(-t+\ln(\ln(\rvert u_0\lvert))$$

Does it look correct to you? I am always troubled by absolute values in ODE. Furthermore, I don't really know what happens when $t=0$ or $u=0$.

Comment: Graphing $u$ on [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qonthvhvp4) indicates that $u_0\ge1$ so the absolute value is not needed.

Comment: If you want to allow negative values of $u_0$ you could multiply your solution by a factor of $\dfrac{u_0}{ |u_0| }$ since it will not be the case ever that $u_0=0$.

Comment: I have added that factor to the function. [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2jla98v71w)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accommodate both positive and negative values of $u_0$ the solution should be in the form

$$ u(t)=\frac{u_0}{|u_0|}\exp(\exp(-t+\ln(\ln(|u_0|))) $$

Graphing the function illustrates that $u_0\in(-\infty,-1)\cup(1,\infty)$ so there is no concern for what happens when $u_0=0$.

Furthermore, letting $t=0$ gives, simply, $u(0)=u_0$ which is as it should b.